# How can i return value for this method?

Tags: java

I have a method which returns the value of my POJO.

My POJO class's name is `Tail`.

```
public Tail getTail(long value1, String value2, int value3) {

    List<Tail> l = /*I get this list via Hibernate. */
    if (l.size() == 1) {
        return (Tail) l.get(0);
    } 
    else if (l.size() > 1) {
        for (Tail t : l) {
            First ik = minorDAO.getFirst(value3, t.getNumber());
            if( ik.getCond().equals("I") ){
                t.setCond("I");
                continue;
            } else {
                return t;   //???????????????               
            }   
        }               
    } else {
        return null;
    }           
}
```

In the else statement inside of the foreach loop where the question mark comment is I want to return t, but if I do this, I get an error stating:

> "This method must return a result of type Tail".

How can I return the value there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with that code you dont get the message:

```
public Tail getTail(long value1, String value2, int value3) {
        List<Tail> l = --> (I get list via Hibernate.)
        if (l.size() == 1) {
            return (Tail) l.get(0);
        } else if (l.size()>1){
            for (Tail t: l) {
                First ik = minorDAO.getFirst(value3, t.getNumber());
                if( ik.getCond().equals("I") ){
                    t.setCond("I");
                    continue;
                } else {
                    return t;
                }   
            }

        }
        return null;

    }
```

If the method has to return `Tail` you must deliver it in any possible case.
For example:

if each element is `true` in this case:

```
if( ik.getCond().equals("I") ){
```

there would be no return. You iterate about the whole list and nothing happens...

Comment: Agree with Stefan.  there needs to be return statement at the end of else if block

Comment: because i must iterate the loop. İf !equals("I") i want to return that t.

Comment: sure but in case there is never an equals true you will never return anything(with your code). But you have to return at least null or you must throw an exception.

Comment: I know and understand this problem. How can i do this with another code? How can i fix my code?